# SSL mixte content - PHP

Tags: php, ssl, mixed

I recently added SSL certificate to my wordpress site but I'm still getting the mixed content error. I looked what triggered it and it's the logo url. 
I installed the force HTTPS plugins but with no lock. The problem is with my theme.

I looked in the source code of the page and I identified the code that is generating the warning.

```
<?php echo esc_url( $header_options['logo'] ); ?
```

This code is generating a http link.

I'm a noobie and can't corect it. So, as a workaround I hard coded the logo url to the code. This is not elegant but it works. Now my browser is displaying my site as secure.

Now I want to understand how I can correct that code so it can generate a https link

Thanks

Comment: you change your site url with https ?

Comment: Go to admin panel and change url of your site. WP generates url based on it.

Comment: I changed that code with link of the logo, and that link is https

Comment: @shukshin.ivan can you tell me where exactly do I have to go

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=where+do+i+change+the+wordpress+site+url

Answer (score 0):

Setting the WordPress URL and Site URL to their HTTPS equivalents should fix this. These settings can be found under "Settings" -> "General".

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working. I also have a plugin that forces all http links to https.